# Delegate responding to selector crash when Sending Data between iOS Devices

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

When sending data from one iOS device to another, I receive these errors.

> > 2012-06-21 10:22:15.509 BulletTime[2324:707] -[DataHandler selectorToCall:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19bfc0
> >     2012-06-21 10:22:15.511 BulletTime[2324:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DataHandler selectorToCall:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19bfc0'
> >     *** First throw call stack:
> >     (0x356c188f 0x37a68259 0x356c4a9b 0x356c3915 0x3561e650 0x356207d3 0xb6fd1 0xb7121 0x3322f61b 0x3561b3fd 0x33110e07 0x33110dc3 0x33110da1 0x33110b11 0x33111449 0x3310f92b 0x3310f319 0x330f5695 0x330f4f3b 0x372b422b 0x35695523 0x356954c5 0x35694313 0x356174a5 0x3561736d 0x372b3439 0x33123cd5 0xb231f 0xb22c4)
> >     terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

I know for sure that this code is causing the crash, but I don't know how to fix it:

```
- (void)sendInfo {
    //Attempting to send info to the other device.
    //Returns to the Data Handler.
    info = (BOOL*)YES;

    //Sets the requestLabel and requestData of the CameraRequestDataProvider object.
    //These are then handled in the DataHandler...
    requestLabel = @"Cam";
    requestData = [@"Cam" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Crash occurs here...

    if (delegateToCall && [delegateToCall respondsToSelector:selectorToCall])

        [delegateToCall performSelector:@selector(selectorToCall:)];
}
```

I have been attempting to figure this out for the past few days with no luck. Any ideas? I would greatly appreciate it!

Got it! Thank you, I fixed that error.

However, now I'm getting this error:

> > 2012-06-21 10:47:16.779 BulletTime[2416:707] ButtonIndex 0, info should be sent here.
> >     2012-06-21 10:47:19.913 BulletTime[2416:707] BTM: attempting to connect to service 0x00000800 on device "Grace's iPad" A4:67:06:F3:EC:2A
> >     2012-06-21 10:47:20.929 BulletTime[2416:707] BTM: connection to service 0x00000800 on device "Grace's iPad" A4:67:06:F3:EC:2A succeeded
> >     2012-06-21 10:47:22.029 BulletTime[2416:707] -[DataHandler selectorToPerformWhenConnectionWasStablished:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1303f0
> >     2012-06-21 10:47:22.032 BulletTime[2416:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DataHandler selectorToPerformWhenConnectionWasStablished:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1303f0'
> >     *** First throw call stack:
> >     (0x356c188f 0x37a68259 0x356c4a9b 0x356c3915 0x3561e650 0x356207d3 0x6c693 0x351cf4ff 0x3568d547 0x35619097 0x351433eb 0x6ce1f 0x3069612f 0x356201fb 0x351e4747 0x35695ad3 0x3569529f 0x35694045 0x356174a5 0x3561736d 0x372b3439 0x33123cd5 0x6b2df 0x6b284)
> >     terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is the DataHandler class? Does it have a method selectorToCall:?

Comment: As far as I know, `selectorToCall` and `selectorToCall:` are two different messages.
Show us delegateToCall class code.

Comment: What does your "`selectorToCall:`" declaration and code look like?

Comment: Ok, all of my classes can be found here: https://github.com/Glchriste/BulletTime

Comment: I don't see `DataHandler` there, and it's the interesting one because its name shows up in the error.  (Which class is the `sendInfo` method in?)

Comment: Please see my updated post about last error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (delegateToCall && [delegateToCall respondsToSelector:selectorToCall])

    [delegateToCall performSelector:selectorToCall];
```

and same mistake in method

```
- (void)cancelInfo:(id)sender {
    [mainViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [delegateToCall performSelector:@selector(selectorToCall:)];    
}
```

need replace to

```
- (void)cancelInfo:(id)sender {
    [mainViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [delegateToCall performSelector:selectorToCall];    
}
```

UPDATE:

in file Device.m same error in method:

```
- (void)triggerConnectionSuccessfull:(NSNotification *)notification
```

replace string

```
[delegateToCallAboutConnection performSelector:@selector(selectorToPerformWhenConnectionWasStablished:)];
```

to string

```
[delegateToCallAboutConnection performSelector:selectorToPerformWhenConnectionWasStablished];
```

and method

```
- (void)triggerConnectionFailed:(NSNotification *)notification
```

also have same error

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the member variable selectorToCall either on line 105 or 110 of `CameraDataProvider` in the github source. That means you don't need the colon at the end of the performSelector call.

Instead of looking for the selector that is set in selectorToCall,

```
 [delegateToCall performSelector:@selector(selectorToCall:)];
```

is looking for a method on DataHandler with the name `selectorToCall` that takes one parameter (because of the colon).

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that error by removing @selector and the semicolon. However, now I am getting a new error (updated at top). I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Alright, fixed both. Now I just have to deal with an unexpected command error exception being thrown by my DataHandler, which shouldn't be too hard to fix (hopefully).